# how does python interact with linux?

Tags: python, linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal

I use `commands.getstatusoutput('some_terminal_command')` to store output of some terminal command in a variable. But am curious to know how does python actually get the output from the terminal? does python has some part of 'Shell' or something?

Comment: There's no need to interact with Terminal to use the shell.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you should use `subprocess` instead of `commands`.  The former is _way_ better (and not deprecated).

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara , I meant to know the code, that says- 'hey terminal, this is the command and give me the output '.

Comment: Terminal is simply not involved.

Comment: how does python bring that output for me, that terminal gives me? what is the code for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ultimately, your call to run a command uses the [fork and exec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork%E2%80%93exec) system calls. These are functions provided by the OS and exposed to most programming languages, which allows the language to start a new process and get its output. It's one of the fundamental building blocks of many modern operating systems.

Note that not all OS's have fork-exec, but If they don't, they will have some sort of system-provided function for starting processes. This is one of the benefits of using a high level language: it hides platform-specific features behind a cross-platform api.

Comment: For clarification, you might note that fork-and-exec requires neither a shell nor a terminal.  Also: +1.

Comment: yeah! that is what I was looking for :)

Comment: `fork`/`exec` is specific to UNIX-style systems -  question was tagged with Ubuntu so it was reasonable to mention them.  However Python is portable and does not depend on an operating system with those features, Windows is an example, where processes are created in a different way (`CreateProcess` is the API).

Answer (score 1):

If you [read the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/commands.py#L56) You'll see that it uses the `os.popen` call. What's intriguing, however, is that `os.popen` isn't defined in the `os.py` module that I can find.

Eventually and with [some help](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31668272#31668272) I was able to find the [posixmodule source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Modules/posixmodule.c#L4597-L4619), which verifies that the way that python interacts with Linux, at least when `PYCC_GCC` is defined, is via the `popen` function. According to `man popen`, that means:

> The popen() function opens a process by creating a pipe, forking, and invoking the shell.

If you look through this module you'll see that the module defines some other approaches for different OSes (like OSX, NT, etc.)

Comment: Line 1023 of `os.py` in Python 3.5.2, Python 2.7.12 starts defining the various different ones around line 658